# React-native two views with image between

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm new to react-native and I want to do a page that basically has 2 `View`s and between them has a rounded `Image` (like in the image) , i know how to do 2 `View`s but I don't know how to put the `Image` there correctly.
[image]

Comment: Please attach some code

Comment: Hey, hm attaching code doesn't matter i think, i just don't know how to position an image rounded like the example i did. Two views is very basic just the image thing i don't know how to do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: 'grey'}}></View>
    <View style={{flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: 'black', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Image
        source={require('./icon.png')} 
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: -40,
          height: 80,
          width: 80}} 
        />
    </View>
  </View>
```

Comment: i will try this tomorrow , thanks :) if it works i will accept the answer

Comment: What seems to be the problem @Brunaine? This definitely should work.

Comment: and its not working on the demo either, it shows like that https://gyazo.com/586186c9612dead80ecadb67feebceaf and i want the image to be at front of both views

Comment: in ios it works but the android is shows on the back? how can i make this work?

Comment: Indeed, looks like an Android bug: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8923.

You could try positioning the view absolutely from the parent view: https://snack.expo.io/BJgLA7Jl-

Comment: it works on the Demo , will try it out in a bit and if it works i will accept your answer, thanks | update your answer maybe to help other people coming here

Comment: it didn't work check this prints : https://gyazo.com/44a2d3eadb6703757edfb5fe47788f1c
https://gyazo.com/e92d7ff7ec253fc04c85a125929ead6a

Comment: Do you understand what you are doing? Your `top` should be `200 - iconHeight / 2` and your `left` should be `Dimensions.get('window').width - iconWidth / 2`.

Comment: oh sorry my bad, i just had to change to (Dimensions.get('window').width - iconWidth ) / 2 and it worked! thanks